# How do I get Listbox to display horizontally in code programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have searched and searched and all I see are `XAML` examples. I want to do this programmatically without `XAML`. Here is the code:

```
        StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
        stackPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        lstBox.Items.Add(stackPanel);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(lstBox);`
```

This does not work since the list remains vertical. I tried making the `Listbox` a child of the `StackPanel` and other combinations unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the elements in the `ListBox` to be displayed horizontally, you should set its `ItemsPanel` property:

```
FrameworkElementFactory stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel));
stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
lstBox.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate(stackPanel);
mainGrid.Children.Add(lstBox);
```

Comment: Thank you @mm8. The code compiled, however it crashes with an `Exception UnHandled System.InvalidOperationException: 'VisualTree of ItemsPanelTemplate must contain a Panel."is not a Panel.'` when `app.Run` is invoked.

Comment: @JW: `StackPanel` is certainly a `Panel`. Did you really copy my code as-is? It should work.

Comment: `mainGrid.Children.Add(lstBox);` this will still bomb the application, the listbox is already added; it's a child of another visual...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ: Is it? How do you know? :) And why would adding a `ListBox` element to a `Grid` "bomb" the application?

Comment: It's my guess as the OP already has this defined... If it's done in code, it's fine.

Comment: A guess? Then your comment and downvote make perfect sense. Or does it?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ it would only bomb the application if the ListBox was already added. However, if that was, then case JW would have received a different error then he did.

Comment: @danielm: Yes. Like for example a compilation error.

Comment: @mm8 `compilation error`, it wouldn't be a compilation error, it would be a run time error.

Comment: @mm8: yes I copied the code verbatim:
`FrameworkElementFactory stackPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory();
            stackPanel.SetValue(StackPanel.OrientationProperty, Orientation.Horizontal);
            lstBox.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate(stackPanel);
            Grid.SetRow(lstBox, 0);
            mainGrid.Children.Add(lstBox);`

I have not added the `lstBox` prior.

Comment: @JW: It should be `new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(StackPanel))`. You are missing the type.

Comment: @mm8 It would be this error at Runtime: `Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget`

Comment: It depends on how `lstBox` is defined. It might be a variable in the code-behing file. Why speculate? This has nothing to do with the question. Besides, the OP has confirmed that it's not added.

Comment: @mm8: when I add the `typeof(stackPanel)` the compiler complains that `stackPanel is a variable but is being used like a type`.

Comment: It should be **S**tack**P**anel and nothing else. Obviously you did not copy my working code sample.

Comment: Please read my answer again. You shouldn't pass a type to the `ItemsPanelTemplate` constructor. You should give it a `FrameworkElementFactory`.

Comment: @mm8: I am sorry! I feel stupid. You solved my problem, thank you for your patience!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set items panel horizontal in the following way too:

```
var wp = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(WrapPanel));
wp.SetValue(Panel.IsItemsHostProperty, true);
lstBox.ItemsPanel = new ItemsPanelTemplate(wp);         
mainGrid.Children.Add(lstBox);
```

The WrapPanel might be used to keep together items like buttons in a toolbar control.

Answer (score 1):

For an horizontal panel it's better to use a WrapPanel to take benefits of the wrapping elements.
Here is an example for the new year ;-)

[image]

**XAML**

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="280" Height="99" Margin="36,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <WrapPanel x:Name="Wrappanel1" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
     </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**C#**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    additem(Brushes.Orange,"Hello");
    additem(Brushes.Green,"World");
    additem(Brushes.DarkOrchid,"and");
    additem(Brushes.RoyalBlue,"Happy");
    additem(Brushes.Orange, "new");
    additem(Brushes.SteelBlue, "Year");
    additem(Brushes.RoyalBlue, "for");
    additem(Brushes.Green, "2020");
    additem(Brushes.Orange, "All");
    additem(Brushes.DarkOrchid, "the");
    additem(Brushes.Orange, "best");
}

private  void additem(SolidColorBrush BackgroundColor,string information)
{
    Button but = new Button();
    but.Height = 50;
    but.Content = information;
    but.Background = BackgroundColor;
    but.FontSize = 18;
    Wrappanel1.Children.Add(but);
}
```